# How to select and add text to the email with selenium in python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write program, that logins to my e-mail account and sends the mail to the provided recipient. For that I' using selenium.
The problem I'm meeting, that I can't find the correct id or class of the message content block, so the email which I send is empty.

My code's fragment:

```
try:
    bodyElem = browser.find_element_by_id('eml-cke__body')
    bodyElem.send_keys('Some text to send to a recipient')
except:
    print('Was not able to find an element with that name.')
```

I'm using browser inspector, and when I hover on the content box, I get info provided in an image bellow:
[image: Inspector info about a content field]

But when I try to find given element the program finds nothing, so text isn't added.
I want to know what I'm doing wrong when searching for the right id or class for that field and how I can do it correctly.

[The Page Source of "compose message window"](https://pastebin.com/PfwQiGna)

Comment: Update the question with text based relevant HTML along with the complete error stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `send_keys` only for `input` tags